# How to use the SQL Manager to find which extensions use a certain hook?

Tags: hook, sql

How would I go about using the SQL manager to find out which extensions use a specific hook?  I can't find any documentation or query examples on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query...

```
SELECT * FROM exp_extensions WHERE hook = 'hook_youre_looking_for';
```

The `class` column will indicate what Extension it belongs to, and the `method` column will tell you what method (function) to look at in that PHP class.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for the example!

Answer (score 1):

look in the exp_extensions table.  you should find everything you need there